# PHP ldap_bind doesn't do anything and eventually returns 500 internal error

Tags: php, iis, ldap

I am trying to create a login page with ldap. The problem is that `ldap_bind()` doesn't do anything and the website loads very slow when i click "login" button until i get 500 -internal error.

Here is the code:

```
    // Connect to LDAP
    error_log("Connecting...");
    $link_id = ldap_connect('ldaps://' . self::$HOST . ':' . self::$PORT);
    error_log("link_id: ");
    error_log(print_r($link_id,true));
    $bind_result = ldap_bind($link_id, self::$APP_DN, self::$SERVER_PASSWORD);
    error_log(print_r($bind_result,true)); //doesnt go through ldap_bind()
```

`ldap_connect` returns "resource id #6" and the program stops at the line where the ldap_bind is.
What could be wrong here?

Comment: Can you bind from the cmd line (eg. using ldapsearch) when connected (ssh) to your web server ? What are the logs saying (slapd, audit, httpd/php) ?

Comment: Could you please explain me what to do? Sorry i am not familiar :(

Comment: Basically I suggest you to test the connection with a simple ldap client as a 1st step (not from a php script), I don't know much about iis though. Looking at the logs would help.

Comment: Can you post the result of ldap_error after the ldap_bind.

Comment: @heiglandreas There is no error basically. It returns on the browser 500- internal error but on the logs it shows nothing